# If I port forward a computer with my router, is the public IP static?

Tags: router, dns

I need to know this for DNS purposes. If I can, I could create a good home server.

Comment: Whether your public IP is static or dynamic is always a function of the type of internet you are paying for and is not dependent on whether or not you've forwarded a port from your router. Also, most home internet services require you to sign a document that includes the provision that you will not host a server on the connection. You may want to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's dynamic before port forwarding, it will be after.

You could use build-in in many routers Dynamic DNS function (also possible if routers doesn't have them, via Windows/Linux app - like [noip](https://www.noip.com/) or [Dyn](https://dyn.com/dns/)).

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you are port-forwarding has nothing to do with if your public ip is static.

The staticness of any public ip is controlled/determined by the ISP that owns the ip-address.
If you need a static ip for wathever reason you will have to talk to your ISP.

Having said that: For a home-server you often can do without a static IP. Look into dynamic DNS services, that may be a solution for you.
And check the contract you have with your ISP. Running a home-server may be in violation of your contract.